# Is there any way to compile a .py file into a $py.class file using Jython with a fixed Mtime annotation, for reproducible builds?

Tags: python, jython

I want to create $py.class files for Jython in my build which are reproducible, so I can verify easily that nothing has changed. I distribute them in a .jar form without the Python source files, and run them with Jython.

If I do two different builds, the only difference I'm seeing is the [`@MTime` annotation that Jython creates with `ClassFile` objects](https://github.com/jythontools/jython/blob/v2.5.3/src/org/python/compiler/ClassFile.java#L41) -- it looks like there's a way, at least in the Java side of Jython, to pass in an mtime or default to `NO_MTIME`, but  I don't know what the Java equivalent of [`py_compile.compile()`](https://www.jython.org/jython-old-sites/docs/library/py_compile.html) is.

- How can I control the mtime stored in the $py.class file? (I don't care about the filesystem mtime.)
- If I set the mtime myself, does this have any implications for correct operation?